# Show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence, correlation

> > Let $X$ and $Y$ be two discrete random variables with respective probability distributions $\Bbb P(X=x_1)=p_1,\Bbb P(X=x_2) = 1 - p_1$ and $\Bbb P(Y=y_1) = p_2, \Bbb P(Y=y_2)=1-p_2$. Show that if they are uncorrelated then they are independent.

Since $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated we find that $\Bbb E(XY) = \Bbb E(X) \Bbb E(Y)$. So $$\Bbb E(XY) = [x_1p_1 + x_2 (1-p_1)][y_1p_2 + y_2 (1-p_2)].$$

So $\Bbb E(XY) = x_1 y_1 p_1p_2 + x_1 y_2 p_1 (1- p_2) + x_2 y_1 p_2(1-p_1) + x_2y_2 (1-p_1)(1-p_2)$. On the other hand $\Bbb E(XY) = x_1 y_1 \Bbb P(XY=x_1y_1) + x_1 y_2 \Bbb P(XY=x_1y_2) + x_2 y_1 \Bbb P(XY=x_2y_1) + x_2 y_2 \Bbb P(XY=x_2y_2)$.

From these two relations how can I conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are independent? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it clear to you that by a linear change of variables, you can assume $x_1=y_1=1$ and $x_2=y_2=0$?

Comment: Then you are claiming that $x_1-x_2=1$ and $y_1-y_2=1$. Right?

Comment: Well, no, I'm saying that there's a change of coordinates such that the point $(x_1,y_1)$ becomes the point $(1,1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ becomes the origin.

Comment: What is the formula for such change of coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let us do it for $X', Y'$ such that $x_1=y_1=1$ and $x_2=y_2=0$.

Then: $$0=\mathsf{Cov}(X',Y')=\mathbb EX'Y'-\mathbb EX'\mathbb EY'=P(X'=1\wedge Y'=1)-P(X'=1)P(Y'=1)$$

This shows that the events $\{X'=1\}$ and $\{Y'=1\}$ are independent and since both random variables take a.s. at most two distinct values this implies that $X'$ and $Y'$ are independent.

For this note that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ implies that: $$P(A^{\complement}\cap B)=P(B)-P(A\cap B)=P(B)-P(A)P(B)=(1-P(A))P(B)=P(A^{\complement})P(B)$$

In general if $X'$ and $Y'$ are independent then so are $aX'+b$ and $cY'+d$.

From this we conclude that also $X=(x_1-x_2)X'+x_2$ and $Y=(y_1-y_2)Y'+y_2$  are independent.

Comment: Clear as crystal. Thank you very much @drhab for your help.

Comment: You are welcome.